# Reading illegible document from Scotland's People?

Tags: marriage-records, scotland, images, palaeography

[image]

I recently started using Scotland's People, and the first article I am looking at is here and I find it completely illegible, perhaps due to scanning.

Can anyone help me to read the information in the top entry for the marriage of Alexander Barclay Ormond?

Comment: That really is an exceptionally bad image. I'd be tempted to contact them via the contact form on the site and ask to get it re-scanned!

Comment: Related : https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10493/how-can-i-process-this-image-to-extract-more-of-the-information

Comment: This is why scanning to black and white instead of greyscale is a bad idea. It saves a bit of storage space and yields horrible scans.

Comment: This is my first experience actually paying for records, and I must say I am disappointed! At least it can't get any worse and I may well contact them to rescan

Comment: They've always been very gracious about sending improved versions when I've contacted them, so I wouldn't hesitate to do so.

Comment: I think the older scans were poorer quality.  The more recently scanned ones are much clearer.  As others have noted they will normally respond pretty quickly to a request for a (free) rescan.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyPerl I've sent a request over, though I think I'm getting used to reading these poorer records and have almost decoded it now

Comment: Did you ever get an improved quality image?

Comment: @sempaiscuba yes they sent me an email with it on. They seem very reasonable about these kinds of things and solved it fairly quickly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably going to take a bit of work. In general, it's best to start by trying to identify letter and word shapes according to what you know, and what you expect to be there, then move onto the unknowns.

So you know you must have "Alexander Barclay Ormerod" somewhere, and that's actually fairly clear at the top of the second column. Other parts may be common - the lower part in the first column, I think, reads "After Banns according to the forms of the Church of Scotland", which appears to be standard wording in Scottish marriages.

In small steps like that, you can build a small "dictionary" of words using the bits you can be confident of, and that should help identify unknown sections by matching or eliminating likely words.

And don't ignore the other records on that page (and in that set, if available). Anything written by the same hand could help clarify the records you have, so look around for similar patterns. For example, "Dundee" in the "At" field of the rightmost column is much clearer in the lower record than in the upper one, but it is surely the same word in both.

Also look at better-defined scans of Scottish marriage records of the same era, if you can find them, to identify some more common text segments.

Try to decipher what you can like this, and then come back if there are any specific parts you still have trouble with.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/1394/4485) to a related question, and the links therein.